# Call Artisan Command via URL

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

In my route I have

```
Route::get('artisan/{command}/{param}', 'CacheController@show');
```

And in my controller i have

```
public function show($id, $param)
{
    $artisan = Artisan::call($id,['flag'=>$param]);
    $output = Artisan::output();
    return $output;
}
```

I want to be able to call `route:cache` and `cache:clear` by accessing `domain.com/artisan/cache/clear` or `route/cache` but when I call them it returned something like this

> Command "cache" is not defined.

It only called cache, not `cache:clear` what possibility going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling an `id` when you have called it `command`

so your function needs to look like this

```
public function show($command, $param) {
    $artisan = Artisan::call($command,['flag'=>$param]);
    $output = Artisan::output();
    return $output;
}
```

So your URL can look like this `domain.com/artisan/cache/clear` which means that you are calling this route

```
Route::get('artisan/{command}/{param}', 'CacheController@show');
```

So you need `$command` intead of `$id`

Comment: :| you only changed the variable name! my problem was the same but it doesn't solved by your answer

Answer (score 4):

Modify your code like this:

```
    $artisan = \Artisan::call($command.":".$param);
    $output = \Artisan::output();
    return $output;
```

Flag argument is used to pass the arguments of an artisan command.

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135339/how-can-i-call-command-schedule-via-url-on-the-laravel